# Determine the character set of string

Tags: c++, utf-8

as default, the std::string in my machine is GBK, and the string i wrote in program is encoding with gbk, but sometimes i recive datas from server and the datas is encoding with UTF-8, I want to determine which the chatacter set the string is using. I saw the utf-8 and gbk encoding method, it's hard to complete it by self.

Comment: `std::string` is encoding agnostic. It does not care about the encoding of the bytes you put into it. As such, it is better described as a "byte string" than a "text string". So it does not make sense to claim that "as default, the `std::string` in my machine is GBK". When you get a string from somewhere, that somewhere also has to tell you which encoding it uses. You can not reliably guess this just from the contents of the string.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a `std::string` contains UTF-8 content, decode it as UTF-8 and see if it fails.

To check if a `std::string` contains GBK, decode it as GBK and see if it fails.

There are plenty of conversion libraries available, such as [ICONV](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) and [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), which are usually preinstalled on most platforms.  Or use platform specific APIs, like [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows (GBK is covered by codepages 936 and 54936, and UTF-8 is covered by codepage 65001).

Or just write your own decoder (UTF-8 only takes a few dozen lines of code).  You can find details about the bit layouts of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) and [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) on Wikipedia.